# Shorter way to write if else statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

```
<?php
  $typeface = $page->typeface();
    if($typeface == '') {
  } else {
      echo '<li><span>Typeface: </span>'.$typeface.'</li>';
  }
?>
```

I initially tried the PHP code below but it would still output the HTML: 
`<li><span>Typeface: </span></li>` even if the string was empty.

```
<?php $typeface =  $page->typeface(); 
  if (!empty($typeface)): ?>
    <li><span>Typeface: </span><?php echo $typeface ?></li> 
  <?php endif; ?>
```

So my question is, how can I write the code at the very top in a shorter way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$typeface = trim($page->typeface());
if($typeface != '')
    echo '<li><span>Typeface: </span>'.$typeface.'</li>';
```

EDIT: (removing new lines)

```
$typeface = trim(str_replace(array("\r", "\r\n", "\n"), '', $page->typeface()));
if($typeface != '')
    echo '<li><span>Typeface: </span>'.$typeface.'</li>';
```

Comment: I would apply a trim also just in case.

Comment: @PeterKiss What do you mean trim? I do have an empty line if the value is empty. How would I go about removing that?

Comment: if(trim($page->typeface()) != '') { /* ... */ }

Comment: The trim still leaves a blank line.

Comment: Really appreciate this @vlcekmi3

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
(isset($typeface) && !empty($typeface))?echo "<li><span>Typeface: </span>".$typeface."</li>":"";
```

Comment: @ChristopherBurton Edited...Try now

Comment: That works. I'm still having an issue with an empty line in view source, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
($typeface=="")?echo "":echo '<li><span>Typeface: </span>'.$typeface.'</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the return type of `$page->typeface()` method, and the placement of the code (looks like you're on a template view), I might opt for:

```
<?php if ($typeface === $page->typeface()): ?>
    <li><span>Typeface: </span><?=$typeface?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

PHP docs here:

[Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/200666/922323) for cautions you should consider when using `<?=...?>` short tags.

An alternative to `<?=...?>` would be: `<?php echo $typeface; ?>`.

Hope that helps!

---

## EDIT:

Actually, I second-guessed myself earlier (I blame sleep deprivation). I originally had this code (except for the `trim()`):

```
<?php if ($typeface = trim($page->typeface())): ?>
    <li><span>Typeface: </span><?=$typeface?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Where I'm setting the variable `$typeface` in the `if()`. This technique should shorten your code by a line.

Here's a working example using simple strings:

```
<?php $foo = ""; ?>
...
<?php if ($typeface = trim($foo)): ?>
    <li><span>Typeface: </span><?=$typeface?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

... outputs: Nothing.

```
<?php $foo = 'I\'m a string!'; ?>
...
<?php if ($typeface = trim($foo)): ?>
    <li><span>Typeface: </span><?=$typeface?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

... outputs: `<li><span>Typeface: </span>I'm a string!</li>` (obviously, missing the opening and closing `<ul></ul>`.

Comment: For some reason that still outputs `<li><span>Typeface: </span></li>` when there is no value.

Comment: @ChristopherBurton When I first posted the code, I had `$typeface = $page->typeface()` (copy/paste error). I changed it to `$typeface === $page->typeface()` (note the `===`). Hopefully that's why it's not working for you?

Comment: I still get the same result.

Comment: Gosh, I'd hate to waste your time... You might trim, like the others are saying: `<?php if ($typeface === trim($foo)): ?>`? When I test using these vars: `<?php $typeface = "blah"; $foo = "blah"; ?>`, where `$foo` is my version of `$page->typeface()`, it works for me... What does $page->typeface() expected return type/value? I assume it's an empty/non-empty string return? Again, I don't mean to waste your time (looks like you're getting a ton of great answers already). :)

Comment: @ChristopherBurton Even though you've got your answer, I've updated my answer... My original thinking stands (see my **EDIT** above). I **sometimes** like assigning vars in an `if()` check... Makes for on less line of code to juggle. If that does not work, then you might need to apply a more hardcore trim like the one used in the [solution above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13776080/922323). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
$typeface = $page->typeface();
echo $res=($typeface != '')?'<li><span>Typeface: </span>'.$typeface.'</li>':'';
```